# Eignen Matrix state vector averaging over some samples for Orientation calculation

Tags: c++11, orientation, eigen, kalman-filter, eigenvector

I have an Eigen Matrix like

```
#define KF_STATEVEC_T      Eigen::Matrix<double,KF_STATEDIM,1>
```

Orientation calculation from this matrix is done as shown below :

```
180.0*atan2( state[3],state[2] )/PI;
```

I receive samples every second and I want to average out the orientation values over let's say 2 samples. Here's my code

.h file :

```
  std::queue<KF_STATEVEC_T> QOrientation;
  KF_STATEVEC_T AvgOrientation;
```

.cpp

```
     KF_STATEVEC_T state = Kf.getCurrentState();
     QOrientation.push(state);
     if(QOrientation.size() > 2)
     {
         auto tmp = QOrientation.front();
         AvgOrientation -= tmp;
         QOrientation.pop();
         AvgOrientation += state;
         AvgOrientation /= QOrientation.size();
     }
     else
     {
         AvgOrientation += state;
         AvgOrientation /= QOrientation.size();
     }
```

2 questions:

1. Is this method of averaging the state vector correct? If not what is
   the correct way of averaging Eigen Matrix state vector in above case.
2. The orientation lies in range 0-180(quadrants above x-axis) -> -180 to 0 (quadrants below x-axis), I cannot directly take average. Should these be converted to 0-360 range and then averaged? Or we can achieve this by averaging the state vector itself?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Please provide a [mre]! 2) By orientation you mean 2D-orientation (orientation in the plane)? 3) How do you calculate `state[3], state[2]`? Is it always a unit vector? 4) What do you want the average of -179 and +179 degrees to be? 0 degrees or +-180 degrees? (Orientations are not a Euclidean vector space, so generally, you can't average them by just adding them up).

Comment: 1. This vector is calculated by Kalman Filter `KF_STATEVEC_T state = Kf.getCurrentState();` (cannot provide code on how this is calculated). 2/3. Yes, this is 2D orientation and `state[3], state[2]` represent `y and x component of velocity` of the object respectively. 4. Average of -179 and 179 should be +-180 degree. (That was my 2nd question, I assume we could average the state vector to achieve this, not sure though!)

Comment: Yes, taking the atan2 of the average direction vector should work reasonably well for 2D orientations. If you already have a KF, why do you need to average the current state with the previous (?) state?

Comment: Because of fluctuation, i thought may be taking average over 3-4 samples would reduce any sharp change in orientation. But taking average of vector gives `bad result`[done black box testing, not seen how the state vector have changed with averaging.]